# preloader for parallax webpage with multiple HQ background images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is anyone able to help with implementing a loading screen for a single webpage that contains many large image files set as the background (background-size: cover;) for multiple divs? it's excessive by far - they have a 1920px width, there are around 68 of them, approximately 100mb in total - but i'm so far a total novice at optimizing for the web.

i'm looking at the loading screen used on this website: http://thecolorshop.co/product/ginger/
i don't mind any suggestions - jquery is fine

i know loading time isn't exclusively determined by the size of the page's files (but i will reduce the size of my images to at least 1500px width) but would anyone also have any ideas how this page loads very quickly, with minimal lag: http://brookandlyn.com/fieldtrip/#intro - though it is a single parallax webpage with a few high res photos (1920px in width).

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files size of an image is not just down to the actual pixel size but also you can reduce it by using either photoshop or using a service like http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ that will make your images smaller in file size or try this free website image editor https://pixlr.com ..

100m website page is a big no no! the load time and bandwidth to actual display it would be to much for mobile data and also is not necessary to have in this day and age.

You can use lazy load image that will help to load images as needed to reduce the loading of all the images from the start.

I don't think that a loading screen will help you first of all you need to reduce the file sizes of the image so that they are smaller in mb 100mb divided by 62 is 1.6mb per image so you could reduce the image to around 300kb this would mean that your total images would then come to around 18mb this will have a huge impact on your loading of the site and then give you a base to start to optimise even more with lazy load images and other tools.

Hope this helps you to get started on getting the file size down.

Comment: thank you very much for the links :) looking at the compression tools, i've decided to purchase jpegmini (maybe also use imageoptim) and reduce the file dimensions - and potentially the quality as well, depending on the final size after compression. also, i will split the page into three parts, which in a way works better for me. thank you again for your help

Comment: Also after your done try to use the help provided by services like :
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/
http://gtmetrix.com
They will show you where your site speed can be adjusted to get the better site speed.

Comment: cool, thank you - my sites only very young and so far one page, but it will be good in the learning process knowing what generally seems to affect site speed. thanks again

Comment: hey, just to follow up - i was able to reduce the collective image file size to around 20mb while reducing the width to 1500px, 80q, and jpegmini - i might use imageoptim too (though it strips color profiles), so thanks for your help :)

Comment: It might be worth trying to use http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ they might be reduced a little more without stripping the colours you can try and see the result if it works you would save more if not you have not lost anything. also http://gtmetrix.com/ after testing your website there is a Optimize images rating clicking it will then give you a link to the optimised image and how much you saved on the image. Try them both and hope it saves some more as 20mb is better but still way to high as google ranks sites on page speed. The site you referenced images are around 230kb. Good luck!